# Selecting particular months over a range of years pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy, text-files, jupyter

I have imported a time series that I resampled to monthly time steps, however I would like to select all the years with only March, April, and May months (months 3,4, and 5).

Unfortunately this is not exactly reproducible data since it's a particular text file, but is there a way to just isolate all months 3, 4, and 5 of this time series?

```
# loading textfile

mjo = np.loadtxt('.../omi.1x.txt')

# setting up dates
dates = pd.date_range('1979-01', periods=mjo.shape[0], freq='D')

#resampling one of the columns to monthly data
MJO_amp = Series(mjo[:,6], index=dates) 

MJO_amp_month = MJO_amp.resample("M").mean()[:-27] #match to precipitation time series (ends feb 2019)

MJO_amp_month_normed = (MJO_amp_month - MJO_amp_month.mean())/MJO_amp_month.std()

MJO_amp_month_normed

1979-01-31    0.032398
1979-02-28   -0.718921
1979-03-31    0.999467
1979-04-30   -0.790618
1979-05-31    1.113730
                ...   
2018-10-31    0.198834
2018-11-30    0.221942
2018-12-31    1.804934
2019-01-31    1.359485
2019-02-28    1.076308
Freq: M, Length: 482, dtype: float64


print(MJO_amp_month_normed['2018-10'])

2018-10-31    0.198834
Freq: M, dtype: float64
```

I was thinking something along the lines of this:

```
def is_amj(month):
    return (month >= 4) & (month <= 6)

seasonal_data = MJO_amp_month_normed.sel(time=is_amj(MJO_amp_month_normed))
```

but I think my issue is the textfile isn't exactly in pandas format and doesn't have column titles...

Comment: If your index is datatime dtype, then you can use `df[df.index.month.isin([3,4,5])]`.

Comment: Perfect thank you! this works! Feel free to add your solution as an answer and I will mark it correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `month` attribute of [pd.DatetimeIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html#pandas-datetimeindex) with `isin` like this:

```
df[df.index.month.isin([3,4,5])]
```